# How do I "upload" tags to Gerrit using repo?

Tags: git, android-source, gerrit, repo

I have inherited an Android project that uses the Gerrit and Repo tools to manage the Git repositories on a VM.  My normal work flow involves using the **git add** and **git commit** commands to work on my local branch and using **repo sync** and **repo upload** to update the remote.  After **repo upload** I use Gerrit to approve changes for myself and others.  This is working okay except that I cannot figure out how to upload the tags I have created on my local branch. I have tried using the **git push --tags** command directly but I get an error the the repository is not exported.  I assume that is because the **repo upload** command does something different and the **git push** command is trying to violate the rules.  I am obviously new to this and would appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Comment: I've answered the general question about how to upload tags. If you still have problems with `git push` as described in my answer, open a separate questions with additional details.

Answer (score 0):

For upload purposes, the Repo tool is only capable of uploading commits for review. It can't upload tags. You can use `git push --tags` just like you would with any other Git server. Just make sure you have the necessary permissions; in particular you'll need [Push Annotated Tag](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push_annotated) for refs/tags/* (and probably [Push Signed Tag](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push_signed) too), [Forge Author](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_forge_author), and [Forge Committer](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_forge_committer). The latter two are required for you to be allowed to upload tag objects created by someone other than yourself.