# Cannot push tags using git push --tags and need help to debug

Tags: git, android-source, gerrit, repo

I have a local git repository and need to push annotated tags to the remote but the command **git push --tags** fails with the following error: "fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported"

Note: This is a follow up to this question: [original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27911273/4447004)

This is an Android OS project so we are using the repo tool to manage the dozens of repositories and the gerrit tool for code reviews.  The normal workflow works fine meaning I can modify code, upload, review, approve, etc. but only the tags are giving me problems so I assume my network/user privileges are okay.  This project is something I inherited so I did not set it up and am very new to git/gerrit/repo etc.

After spending some time on this I think what is likely happening is that our git server is configured not to allow pushes except from the gerrit "user" and we use **repo upload** to submit changes to gerrit and when approved it is gerrit that does the push.  This is just a total guess from someone that is just starting to look at this and may be completely dumb.

Whether my guess is right or not... I still am not sure what to do.

Comment: Do you have all permissions listed in my answer to your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911273/how-do-i-upload-tags-to-gerrit-using-repo)? I just updated the answer with a couple of additional permissions.

Comment: I have tried to add the correct permissions but still no success.  Here is a snapshot of my gerrit access: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86741684/gerrit.png

Comment: I don't see Forge Committer Identity anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried several options with no success.  Here is my most recent access settings: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86741684/gerrit1.png

Answer (score 0):

You must have refs/tags/* access permission to push tags to your repository. This permission can be configured in Gerrit. Required your SCM to add your account in a group, and allow members in this group to push tags to repository (with refs/tags/* access permission). Of course the tags will not go through the review procedure.

Comment: I have tried to add the correct permissions but still no success.  Here is a snapshot of my gerrit access: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86741684/gerrit.png

Comment: The snapshot shows your permissions are OK for pushing annotated tags. I also have the Android OS project and git/repo/gerrit as your case. Usually I push a tag with command: $ git push <remote-name> <tag-name>. And using repo to execute git commands for all git repository if each git repository has the tag to push: $ repo forall -c 'git push <remote-name> <tag-name>'  .  Will you just try to push a single tag first? And see whether it works or not. I didn't use "$ git push --tags" since I'm not sure all local tags should be pushed to server.